# what happens when the id serial reaches it's maximum possible value when inserting a record

Tags: postgresql

As the title says:
-What happens when the id field reaches its limit when auto-incrementing ?

Is there an overflow ? Can we program it to restart from 0 like a rotating index by deleting those indices beforehand?

Comment: Before investing too much time in worrying about such things, are you *actually likely* to reach the overflow limit in your actual usage? In most circumstances, you will need to have created literally billions of rows before this happens.

Comment: A sequence generates `bigint` values. If you "burn" 10000 values per second, 24 hours a day 365 days a year, it will take 29247120 years until the sequence is exhausted. And that is only considering positive values. If you make the sequence start with `-9223372036854775808` instead, you have twice the time

Comment: wow...lol.ok thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hit the limit for the data type of the column, you will get an error whenever you try to insert a new row:

```
nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "sequence_name"
```

You can change the sequence to restart from 0, but that won't help you, as you will end up with primary key violation errors. You can restart the sequence at a very low negative number and use up the negative numbers to delay the inevitable some more.

The inevitable is that at some point you will run out of numbers for your data type, and you will have to modify the table to use a numeric data type that allows a wider range of numbers. That change is very unpleasant and typically means a longer down time (although there are complicated ways to work around that).